# Avocado plant is dying

Tags: plant-health, avocado

I planted an avocado plant from seed about two years ago. It grew to about 1.5 meters with some leaves. But suddenly, it started drying from its middle. I truncated and pruned it from that point but the drying continues. It has some little buds that didn't change from the time that the drying started.

[image: (A photo of it at this time is attached)]

Is there any solution to recover it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shoot, another instance of too big a pot for the size of plant.  Too wet. Roots are rotting and not happy thus the top growth is dying.  Sorry sweetie.  You are going to have to try again, yes?  See some of the other question/answers about avocado germination and care.  A vastly smaller pot, 4" would be a start. Only potting soil, no rocks or gravel below the soil in the pot above the drainage hole.  Just soil.  Do not water when the soil is moist for the upper 1" and we are talking about the 4" size pot, not your 12" in your picture.  (is it 12"???)

Purchase bottled distilled water, do not use tap water.  I can see signs of high salts on your clay pot.  Clay is great!  Tap water is not.

Comment: Why no gravel above the drainage hole?

Comment: Oh I am so very happy that you asked!!  I had to actually teach my master gardener classes I was taking about this subject.  This is sort of an upside down perched water table.  Envision the soil above with small pore spaces and larger rock, pebbles with large pore spaces below...all of the small pore spaces have to be saturated before the water is able to enter the realm of large pore spaces.  Saturated soil is TOO WET for anything other than aquatic plants who are able to pull oxygen out of the water.  This completely negates 'good' drainage for plants in pots.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few of things to consider with most potted plants and specifically to Avocado seeds. After 2 years I would think nutrients may be the problem here.

- Enough **Nutrients** (have you replaced any soil)
- Enough **Sunlight**
- Enough **Water** (2-3 times a week)
- **Proper drainage** (no soggy soil)
- **Seed should be just under the top of the soil**

I would like to also add root bound. The other plant looks good although that pot looks too small for the size.